# What's the name of this non-associative property: (ab)c = (ac)b

Tags: abstract-algebra

This property looks interesting because relates to associativity and commutativity:

- associativity and commutativity implies this property.
- associativity, this property and inverse elements implies commutativity.
- commutativity and this property implies associativity.

But in Wikipedia [List of Usual properties of Non-associative algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-associative_algebra#Usual_properties) this property does not appear. This is not usual?

Comment: Why is "associativity and this property implies commutativity" true? Could you kindly provide a proof or a source? My reason for asking this comes from the algebra generated by $\{x,y,z\}$ with products zero except for $xz=y$. This algebra is nilpotent of index 3, therefore associative, moreover it also satisfies you identity but it's not commutative.

Comment: @2ndyearfreshman In fact it is also necessary to have inverse element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we denote by $R(x)$ the right multiplication operator for an algebra $(A,\cdot)$, defined by $R(x)(y)=x\cdot y$,
then $(a\cdot b)\cdot c=(a\cdot c)\cdot b$ for all $a,b,c$ is equivalent to the operator identity
$$
R(b)R(c)=R(c)R(b).
$$
In other words, the right multiplication operators commute.
Such algebras arise among other topics in the study of affine actions on Lie groups, see [this paper](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_34_lr_algebras.pdf) for example. We called a subclass *LR-algebras*.